# Issue Calling WCF Service From System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I am struggling hard to configure a WCF Service and Client.  In short, I'm working on solution that has a C# Winform fuel server program that needs to host a WCF Service.  The primary function of the fuel server is to interface with hardware that controls fuel dispensers.

The fuel server is a simple application that hosts a WCF Service that is accessible to client applications.  The WCF Service exposes methods that allow the clients to authorize, deauthorize, get the status of pumps, etc...  The service class accomplishes this by executing methods on a COM object that provides access to the dispenser controllers. I have successfully generated and hosted the service using the .NET configuration utilities.

The clients to the service are also C# Winform applications that basically provide a UI for viewing the dispenser statuses and interacting with them (i.e. authorize, deauthorize, etc...).  When the clients first start up, they get a proxy to the service and call a few methods to initialize (i.e. set pump prices, etc...).  All of these calls to the service are successful.

But, once the initialization is complete the client adds a PumpWidget UserControl for each dispenser to a panel.  Then a System.Windows.Forms.Timer object is enabled to tick every 1000ms for each widget.  Inside the tick event, the client gets a proxy to the WCF service and calls a method on the service to get the status.  All of these service calls are failing with a message stating that the endpoint could not be found.

Can anyone tell me whether or not it is safe to call a WCF Service from within a System.Windows.Forms.Timer object?  I cannot figure out why all the calls to the service are succeeding outside of the timer event while the calls inside of the event handler are failing.

Comment: Are you sure the WCF service itself is still running well by the time the client calls fail? Are you able to verify this with a simple WCF test client?

Comment: Yes, i am able to verify that the WCF service is running the entire time with the wcftestclient.exe

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is some type of threading issue but, i'm having no luck

Answer (score 0):

There are three timer controls in the .NET Framework:

- A Windows-based timer, which is always in the Visual Studio Toolbox (System.Windows.Forms.Timer)
- A server-based timer, which you can add to the Visual Studio Toolbox (System.Timers.Timer)
- A thread timer, which is available programmatically (System.Threading.Timer)

If you are using Windows Forms and probably updating a UI, use System.Windows.Forms.Timer.

For server-based timer functionality, you might consider using System.Timers.Timer, which is also more accurate and has additional features.

The third one, System.Threading.Timer, uses a separate thread for it’s operation. If you need to do an asynchronous job periodically, it may be useful.